# What is open on All Saints Day (1 November) in Hungary?

Tags: sightseeing, public-holidays, hungary

Hungary celebrates All Saints Day as a public holiday. What will be open in terms of tourist attractions?

I've been told of some specific museums which will be closed (the National Museum most notably), but other museum websites make no mention of whether they will be open (eg the House of Terror). A friendly Romanian on the train told me that "only restaurants" will be open -- was he right? What about open air "museums" like the statue park?

Comment: If there can be made generalizations I think that would be useful as part of an answer (eg. "As a Catholic holy day of obligation, churches will be celebrating mass and will follow Sunday visiting schedule/be closed to visitors.") Otherwise Budapest would be an appropriate focus.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wish there was more time available to write this up but just treat it as a Sunday. "Vasár- és ünnepnapokon" is the usual way to say when something is open, translates to "sundays and holidays", it's rarely separated. The law dictating employee-employer relations treats them almost the same, the exceptions won't affect you. (2012. évi I. törvény 101. § (1), 102. § (1))

Edit: November 1 and 2 is also when many will visit cemeteries to remember their dead. While theoretically also just a holiday, please be mindful of this day is sorrowful for many and proceed accordingly.